# How do i change Object to String in a class which extends AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm learning from Google's Android developing tutorial and i came across a problem.
In Android's [Connecting to the Network Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#AsyncTask) it says to create a class that extends AsyncTask.

So when I wrote the class it automatically implements the method as follows:

```
private Object doInBackground(Object... args) {..}  //it's fine
```

but when i try writing just as it says in the tutorial:

```
private String doInBackground(String... args) {..} //it gives an error
```

and the error says:

```
The method doInBackground(String...) of type MainActivity.DownloadWebpageText must override a superclass method.
```

So how do I change Object to String without getting an error there?

Comment: An upvote from me as well for a concise question and following through with your promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you extend AsyncTask you must define the inputs to the background, progress, and post execute methods.  Like this

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>
```

Which would define a class that extends AsyncTask and takes as input String and returns a Boolean to the onPostExecute method.

Comment: Thanks it worked!
Had to put AsyncTask<String, Void, String> though but that's it. :)
Sorry i can't upvote your post, still need 3-4 more rep.

Comment: @FilipV. If you accept Flynn81's answer you'll earn 2 more rep... :)

Comment: @FilipV. : I've upvoted your question which has given you more rep.